# Rebus puzzle - An awkward question

Tags: wordplay, visual, rebus

I'm from [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/users/Scratch---Cat). We're planning on building the Scratch Space Academy. Many of my friends, such as Bi, Tri, Quadri, Penta, joined us too. When we got to the site, suddenly, a worker asked me an awkward question.

> What's your name?

---

I replied with this rebus.

```
|             |
|\           /|
| \         / |
|  \       /  |
|   \     /   | 
|    \   /    |
|     \ /     |
|      -      |
 -------------
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
 -------------

This is one of my names.
```

---

This is a rebus puzzle.

> Solve it.

Answer (score 5):

Is it...

> MONO, as in "M on O"?

Comment: Yes, but please read the background.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by reading the background?

Comment: The friends' names are in Latin, but the solution of the rebus is in Greek? (No idea if this is what OP means, just spitballing here.)

Comment: @Bass The question says: "This is one of my names"

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> UNI

Like the answer above, but follows the pattern laid out in the riddle according to the names of your friends.

Comment: It could be that all of them are latin cardinal prefixes,but then the question is wrong, because it should be "du" instead of "bi"  ??

Comment: @balazs.com rot13(Havcrq, ovcrq, dhnqevcrq, cragncrq...V'z abg fher nobhg gur ebbgf, ohg gurfr cersvkrf frrz yvathvfgvpnyyl fvzvyne nppbeqvat gb zl vaghvgvba. Gurer jnf ab "gev" gubhtu, jrveqyl rabhtu...)

Comment: See comment in the previous answer

Comment: @Scratch---Cat rot13(Pbhyq vg or "zbaxrl" gura? "Zbab" vf Fcnavfu sbe zbaxrl...)