# Themed Boggle Grids Continued

Tags: language, letters, board-games

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #7: Board games](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/monthly-topic-challenge-7-board-games?cb=1).</sub>

---

Click [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112239/) for the rules.

Here are some more themed Boggle grids that I created or discovered. Some of these may be references to other board games.

Digraphs are not used here.
Some of these grids may be too large (or unsuitable) for a real Boggle set.

**Grid 1**

```
M A T J
R N T O
K E H
L U W
```

**Grid 2**

```
G K
N I E E
O D R N T
L B A O
E M P
```

**Grid 3**

```
. P R .
M E T A
O G X G
A L I K
```

**Grid 4**

```
G W O B U
N E T D P
A R T O
H C M S
```

**Grid 5**

```
S I D H
P A E L C
M R T S U
O N D B
```

**Grid 6**

```
C F R U
A E O T
M V I N
D A L P
```

**Grid 7**

```
. F H
U Q U A
E N I T .
O C Z R O T
D U E I E P
. E X D S .
```

**Grid 8**

```
G P L E N
D R E U M
W A T S K
H I C O C
```

**Grid 9**

```
R K B E C U
I A L L J O
F H A O C
F U N A G
I D D
```

**Grid 10**

```
S Ì B Ǎ M
H U P Ī Ú
J I À N Z
Ū X O G
```

---

Task:

> Find the theme of each grid. If the grid is written in a foreign language, please also mention the name of the language.

Hint for Grid 2:

> I intended to use some common knowledge but the words are too short. Unsurprisingly, they're the *first* words of each line in the lyrics to the song, and to make the puzzle more challenging, I chose the *third* words instead.

Hint for Grid 3:

> They're all ["my friends"](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91047/#).

Hint for Grid 5:

> The "S" on the third line can be removed and this can still make a valid grid. (citation needed)

Hint for Grid 6:

> A popular board game in the francophone community.

Hint for Grid 8:

> It's a board game that has been mentioned previously by someone else for this Monthly Topic Challenge.

Hint for Grid 9:

> It's a board game whose name can also be found on the grid. It's played on a [graph](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory#) with 12 vertices.

Hint for Grid 10:

> As you might have prophesied, it refers to another board game as well. (And sorry for the lowercase letter issue, but please pay attention to the diacritics.)

Answer (score 1):

*<sup>A significant partial answer (8/10 solved - 2 and 9 still elude me).</sup>*

---

**Grid 1:**

> The **four [Gospel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel) writers** in the Bible - MATTHEW (blue), MARK (red), LUKE (orange) and JOHN (green).
>
>  [image: Grid 1 solution]

NB For tidiness and ease of explanation, for all subsequent explanatory diagrams I have merely circled the starting initials of the words in the hidden set. Readers should at least now be able to spot the hidden words by inspecting the starting letters of the word lists given below, without the clutter of a lot of lines...

**Grid 2:**

As yet unsolved, but I have spotted...

> ...a potential partial set among the letters: KING, NOBLE(MAN) and BARON(ET) are all present, suggesting a possible link to the aristocracy. However, the clue about 'third words in lines of a song' has completely bemused me...

**Grid 3:**

> **[Metric prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix)** - specifically, those between 10^3 and 10^18: KILO, MEGA, GIGA, TERA, PETA and EXA.
>
>  [image: Grid 3 solved]
>
>  NB GIGA has two possible starting points (marked in red).

**Grid 4:**

> [**Quarks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark) - UP*, DOWN, TOP, BOTTOM, CHARM and STRANGE.
>
>  [image: Grid 4 solved]
>
>  NB TOP has two possible starting points (marked in red).

**Grid 5:**

> **Playing card suits** - CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS and SPADES.
>
>  [image: Grid 5 solved]

**Grid 6:**

> **Chess pieces in French** - CAVALIER (Knight), DAME (Queen), FOU (Bishop), PION (Pawn), ROI (King) and TOUR (Rook).
>
>  [image: Grid 6 solved]

**Grid 7:**

> The numbers 1-16 in French - UNE, DEUX, TROIS, QUATRE, CINQ, SIX, SEPT, HUIT, NEUF, DIX, ONZE, DOUZE, TREIZE, QUATORZE, QUINZE and SEIZE.
>
>  [image: Grid 7 solved]
>
>  NB DEUX has two possible starting points (marked in red), each of which also start one of the words DIX or DOUZE. Also, the starting Q (light blue) is shared by QUATRE, QUATORZE and QUINZE, the starting T (orange) by TROIS and TREIZE, and the starting S by SIX, SEPT and SEIZE.

**Grid 8:**

> Surnames of ***[Cluedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluedo)* suspects** (original game): GREEN, MUSTARD, PEACOCK, PLUM, SCARLET and WHITE.
>
>  [image: Grid 8 solved]
>
>  NB The starting P (green) is shared by PEACOCK and PLUM.

**Grid 9:**

As yet unsolved.

**Grid 10:**

> The names of **pieces in [Xiangqi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiangqi)**, also known as 'Chinese chess' or 'elephant chess' - JIÀNG, SHUÀI, SHÌ, XIÀNG, MǍ, JŪ, PÀO, ZÚ and BĪNG.
>
>  [image: Grid 10 solved]
>
>  NB The starting S (green) is shared by SHUÀI and SHÌ, and the starting J (orange) by JIÀNG and JŪ.

Comment: Grid 10 is indeed Asian, but please pay attention to the diacritics.

Comment: "Digraphs" here means two consecutive letters on one cube, such as "QU". The "Wordament" game also use different digraphs.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat Noted, although that wasn't immediately obvious from the context. It might be better just leaving that instruction out, since I think your images are clear enough as is. I'll remove references to it from my answer anyway.